# Remove unicorn messaging in content editor in CM

Tags: content-editor, unicorn

Is it possible to remove following message in the Content Editor while still allowing `/unicorn.aspx` to work?

> This item is controlled by Unicorn

I don't want changes in the CM to be written down to disk, but still want to be able to sync new development changes into this environment?

I have disabled `Unicorn.DataProvider.config` but If I disable `Unicorn.UI.config`, it removes that message, but I can no longer load `unicorn.aspx`

Answer (score 4):

You could modify the Unicorn.UI.config file and remove the content editor warning:

```
<getContentEditorWarnings>
    <processor type="Unicorn.UI.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.SerializedWarning, Unicorn" />
</getContentEditorWarnings>
```

This should only remove the warnings, but be sure only to remove getContentEditorWarnings, and keep the rest of the config.

Comment: Note in the Habitat project this is also included in Common.Dev.config. You need to remove this as well: https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/src/Project/Common/code/App_Config/Environment/Project/Common.Dev.config